# I can not retrieve the current custom user object from Spring Security Context

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm using LDAP authentication provider (active directory) + JWT authorization filter.

I have my custom user object implementing `UserDetails`, also my user service extends `UserDetailsService`. But when I do:

```
Usuario principal = (Usuario) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

`Principal` is just a string (the username), not my user object.

This is my configuration:

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final LdapProperties ldapProperties;
    private final LdapUserMapper ldapUserMapper;
    private final UserService userService;


    public SecurityConfig(LdapProperties ldapProperties, LdapUserMapper ldapUserMapper, UserService userService) {
        this.ldapProperties = ldapProperties;
        this.ldapUserMapper = ldapUserMapper;
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Entry points
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                        //TODO review
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

//        JwtWebSecurityConfigurer... TODO ?

        // Filters
        http.addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));  // ldap
        http.addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));   // jwt
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();

        // No session will be created or used by spring security
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Need to provide Authorization header
        http.httpBasic();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }





    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        //TODO configure properly
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    public AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() {

        String urls = "";
        for (String url : ldapProperties.getUrls()) {
            urls += url + " ";
        }
        urls = urls.trim();

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                ldapProperties.getBaseEnvironment().get("domain"),
                urls,
                ldapProperties.getBase()
        );
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserMapper); 
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);   
        // comment to connect as anonymous
        provider.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(ldapProperties.getUsername(), ldapProperties.getPassword())
        );
        return provider;
    }
}
```

LdapUserMapper:

```
@Component
public class LdapUserMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public LdapUserMapper(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        Usuario result = (Usuario) userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        //TODO compare roles ? set bloqueado ? ...
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails userDetails, DirContextAdapter dirContextAdapter) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my authorization filter.

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (token != null && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = token.replace("Bearer ", "");
            Authentication authentication = getAuthentication(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(final String token) {

        try {
            DecodedJWT decodedToken = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(jwtSecret)).build().verify(token);
            String username = decodedToken.getSubject();
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username , null, new ArrayList<>());
        } catch (JWTVerificationException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I wasn't aware that I only was passing the username as the `Principal` object. So I changed it to this:

```
Usuario usuario = (Usuario) userService.loadUserByUsername(decodedToken.getSubject());
```

I also removed

```
auth.userDetailsService(userService);
```

From `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` config. That was wrong. My auth provider is LDAP, not the DB.